# Implementação do Ciclo de Vida de uma Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Olá. Sou novo no Desenvolvimento Android e gostaria de entender melhor como construir aplicações mais robustas para essa plataforma. Entendo como funciona o ciclo de vida de uma `Activity` mas queria entender como estruturar melhor minhas aplicações seguindo as boas práticas para tal.

1. Quais dos métodos do ciclo de vida devem ser utilizados para construir a Interface Gráfica de Usuário? Digo, instanciar todas as `Views` e atribuir seus respectivos comportamentos. Apenas o método `onCreate` ou outros métodos também podem ser utilizados?
2. Em que momento devo utilizar o `onStart` e o `onResume`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente, os métodos do ciclo de vida da Activity tem seus momentos de execução.

**Veja abaixo:**

`onCreate()`: É a primeira função a ser executada em uma Activity. Geralmente é a responsável por carregar os layouts XML e outras operações de inicialização. É executada apenas uma vez;

`onStart()`: É chamada imediatamente após a onCreate() – e também quando uma Activity que estava em background volta a ter foco;

`onResume()`: Assim como a onStart(), é chamada na inicialização da Activity e também quando uma Activity volta a ter foco. Qual a diferença entre as duas? A onStart() só é chamada quando a Activity não estava mais visível e volta a ter o foco, a onResume() é chamada nas “retomadas de foco”;

`onPause()`: É a primeira função a ser invocada quando a Activity perde o foco (isso ocorre quando uma nova Activity é iniciada);

`onStop()`: Só é chamada quando a Activity fica completamente encoberta por outra Activity;

`onDestroy()`: A última função a ser executada. Depois dela, a Activity é considerada “morta” – ou seja, nao pode mais ser relançada. Se o usuário voltar a requisitar essa Activity, um novo objeto será contruído;

`onRestart()`: Chamada imediatamente antes da onStart(), quando uma Activity volta a ter o foco depois de estar em background.

Fonte: 
[Artigo
Entendendo o ciclo de vida de uma aplicação Android | DEVMEDIA](https://www.devmedia.com.br/entendendo-o-ciclo-de-vida-de-uma-aplicacao-android/22922)

Comment: Muito obrigado @AntónioMacave pela resposta esclarecedora.